# What is different of ways when using join jpa in spring data jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data

I have i issue with spring data jpa. i don't know why? what is of reason?

issue:
 I have 2 table:
   1. AccessPointDb

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "access_point")
public class AccessPointDb  implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "access_point_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Long accessPointId;

@Column(name = "ap_mac")
private String apMac;

@Column(name = "zone_id")
private Long zoneId;

@Column(name = "description")
private String description;

@Column(name = "created_date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date createdDate;

@Column(name = "created_by")
private Long createdBy;

@Column(name = "updated_date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date updatedDate;

@Column(name = "updated_by")
private Long updatedBy; 


public AccessPointDb() {
    super();
}

public Long getAccessPointId() {
    return accessPointId;
}

public void setAccessPointId(Long accessPointId) {
    this.accessPointId = accessPointId;
}

public String getApMac() {
    return apMac;
}

public void setApMac(String apMac) {
    this.apMac = apMac;
}

public Long getZoneId() {
    return zoneId;
}

public void setZoneId(Long zoneId) {
    this.zoneId = zoneId;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}



public Date getCreatedDate() {
    return createdDate;
}

public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
}

public Long getCreatedBy() {
    return createdBy;
}

public void setCreatedBy(Long createdBy) {
    this.createdBy = createdBy;
}

public Date getUpdatedDate() {
    return updatedDate;
}

public void setUpdatedDate(Date updatedDate) {
    this.updatedDate = updatedDate;
}

public Long getUpdatedBy() {
    return updatedBy;
}

public void setUpdatedBy(Long updatedBy) {
    this.updatedBy = updatedBy;
}

}
```

and
   2.  ZoneDb

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "zone")

public class ZoneDb extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "zone_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Long zoneId;

@Column(name = "zone_name")
private String zoneName;

@Column(name = "description")
private String description;

public ZoneDb() {
    super();
}

public Long getZoneId() {
    return zoneId;
}

public void setZoneId(Long zoneId) {
    this.zoneId = zoneId;
}

public String getZoneName() {
    return zoneName;
}

public void setZoneName(String zoneName) {
    this.zoneName = zoneName;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

 }
```

In my code. i want to join 2 table above:
i am used code : `"SELECT a.accessPointId, z.zoneName FROM AccessPointDb AS a LEFT JOIN ZoneDb AS z ON z.zoneId = z.zoneId"`;
and create query : `query = em.createQuery(stmt, persistentClass);`

but i receive error:

```
antlr.SemanticException: Path expected for join!

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! [SELECT a  FROM com.sbd.cms.data.entities.AccessPointDb AS a LEFT JOIN ZoneDb AS z ON z.zoneId = z.zoneId  WHERE 1=1 ]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! [SELECT a  FROM com.sbd.cms.data.entities.AccessPointDb AS a LEFT JOIN ZoneDb AS z ON z.zoneId = z.zoneId  WHERE 1=1 ]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:384)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:246)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:491)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
    at com.sbd.cms.data.repository.implement.AccessPointRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a5b2c11f.search(<generated>)
    at com.sbd.cms.biz.accessPoint.AccessPointBusinessImplement.search(AccessPointBusinessImplement.java:42)
    at com.sbd.cms.web.api.controller.AccessPointController.search(AccessPointController.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:115)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! [SELECT a  FROM com.sbd.cms.data.entities.AccessPointDb AS a LEFT JOIN ZoneDb AS z ON z.zoneId = z.zoneId  WHERE 1=1 ]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1679)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1608)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:313)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:347)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy93.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy93.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.sbd.cms.data.repository.implement.GenericRepositoryImplement.findByQuery(GenericRepositoryImplement.java:189)
    at com.sbd.cms.data.repository.implement.GenericRepositoryImplement.pagingCustom(GenericRepositoryImplement.java:64)
    at com.sbd.cms.data.repository.implement.AccessPointRepository.search(AccessPointRepository.java:56)
    at com.sbd.cms.data.repository.implement.AccessPointRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$9bda46e0.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.dao.support
```

But I don't know why?

and then when i add many to one in table accessPointDb.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "zoneId")
private ZoneDb zoneDb;
```

and i using query

```
 SELECt a.accessPointId, z.zoneName FROM AccessPointDb AS a LEFT JOIN a.zoneDb AS z ON z.zoneId = z.zoneId
```

or

```
 SELECt a.accessPointId, z.zoneDb.zoneName FROM AccessPointDb AS a
```

it is oki.

but i want know what is difference of the ways above?

Comment: JPQL JOINs are across relations. Your first one is NOT across a relation, it is between two separate entities. See the JPA spec, and the documentation for your JPA provider

Comment: @NeilStockton thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.accessPointId, z.zoneName FROM AccessPointDb AS a LEFT JOIN ZoneDb AS z ON z.zoneId = z.zoneId"
```

This(above query) is a native query thats why it's giving error because you use it with `createQuery` method of EntityManager

```
em.createQuery(stmt, persistentClass);
```

instead of `createQuery` you should use `createNativeQuery` for run native queries.

**Native query** :Native query refers to actual sql queries (referring to actual database objects). These queries are the sql statements which can be directly executed in database using a database client.

**Query** :Query refers to JPQL/HQL query with syntax similar to SQL generally used to execute DML statements(CRUD operations).
In JPA, you can create a query using entityManager.createQuery().

Comment: the query above is not a navtiveQuery because AccessPointDb and ZoneDb is two entities is not tables.

Comment: @ngotiensy, ohh sorry i missed @Table annotation, Actually  `SELECT a.accessPointId, z.zoneName FROM AccessPointDb AS a LEFT JOIN ZoneDb AS z ON z.zoneId = z.zoneId"; and create query : query = em.createQuery(stmt, persistentClass);` in this time your entity AccessPointDb not associated with ZoneDb, and hql/JPQL worked on entity and it associated entities or to elements of a collection of values using a join, because that time ZoneDb was not associated to your AccessPointDb entity so hibernate throw the exception : `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join!`

Comment: thanks for your reply. but i think the diffirent in here is spring data jpa is runing on hibernate, it's not standard of jpa. i will change to run it with elipse link. maybe it is oki.

Comment: @ngotiensy  
Join on unrelated entities is not covered by latest JPA spec (2.1)
However Hibernate 5.1.0+ and EclipseLink 2.4.0+ support ad hoc joins. http://blog.anthavio.net/2016/03/join-unrelated-entities-in-jpa.html
So here it's a valid exception by hibernate because JPA not support unlinked  join.

Comment: https://itblog.inginea.eu/index.php/jpql-enhancements-in-jpa-2-1-and-java-ee-7-part-1/

Comment: @ngotiensy joining the unliked entity is own feature of EclipseLink, not a jpa specification.